# Can't get media query to work for iphone6+ and galaxy S4

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm struggling to get my media queries right on my website. I can't get a working query that differentiate between the iphone 6+ and the samsung galaxy s4. Can anyone point me in a direction to go?

URL: http://poaphotography.com/www2.0/

So far, I have the following three queries in my css:

iphone 6:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), only screen and (max-width: 480px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (    moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    .logo {
        **border: 1px solid red;**
        max-width: 60%;
    }
...
...
}
```

iphone 6+:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (    moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    .logo {
        **border: 1px solid blue;**
        max-width: 60%;
    }
...
...
}
```

galaxy s4:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (    moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    .logo {
        **border: 1px solid green;**
        max-width: 60%;
    }
...
...
}
```

meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The iphone 6 falls through to the query with device-pixel-ratio 2, but since both the iphone 6+ and the S4 has pixel-ratio 3 I need another way of separating them, right?

The problem here is that I get the green border on the logo on iphone 6+ and the galaxy s4 but with very different size on the menu icon and the font-size in the dropdown. I know it's bad practice to target specific devices but so far this is the best I can get, but now I'm kind of stuck...

Comment: I wish the phone companies would collaborate and have a universal screen size. Very frustrating. I have no idea why Apple has come out with 6+ and 5c and iPad mini.

Comment: I think you are trying to be too specific here. Pixel width is pixel width. Find a size the logo looks good at that specific pixel width. Higher pixel density will allow a certain layout to be displayed at a smaller screen size. With the number of devices out there trying to predict height and other factors probably isn't worth it.